# Possible to add CSS to some JS to style disabled checkbox text

Tags: javascript, css, checkbox

I'm using a bit of JS to limit the amount of checkboxes that a user can select in a form I am working on. With this JS, once the limit of 2 is reached, the remaining checkboxes are greyed out.

However, I am using other JS that removes the actual checkbox so that I can style the form anyway I like, so now when the limit is reached, there is no visual cue that the remaining choices cannot be selected.

I am hoping there is a way to style the text in the remaining choices to grey out when the limit of choices is reached.

Here is the JS I am using that greys out the checkboxes. Can I add a css style to this to do what I need?

---

```
$('input:checkbox[name="board_colors[]"]').on('change', function () {
    var nightLifeLimit = $('input:checkbox[name="board_colors[]"]:checked').length;
    if (nightLifeLimit == 2) {
        $('input:checkbox[name="board_colors[]"]').each(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                return;
            }
            else {
                $(this).prop('disabled', true);
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        $('input:checkbox[name="board_colors[]"]').each(function () {
            $(this).prop('disabled', false);
        });
    }
});
```

---

HTML for the checkbox section of the form

---

```
<fieldset>
        <legend>Choose color(s) <small class="fineprint">*choose up to two</small></legend>
            <ul>
                <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="bright_green" value="Bright Green" name="board_colors[]" title="Please choose a color(s)" required minlength="1">
                    <label for="bright_green">Bright Green</label></li>

                <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="teal_blue" value="Teal Blue" name="board_colors[]">
                    <label for="teal_blue">Teal Blue</label></li>

                <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="sea_blue" value="Sea Blue" name="board_colors[]">
                    <label for="sea_blue">Sea Blue</label></li>

                <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="purple" value="Purple" name="board_colors[]">
                    <label for="purple">Purple</label></li>

                <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="magenta_dark_pink" value="Magenta Dark Pink" name="board_colors[]">
                    <label for="magenta_dark_pink">Magenta/Dark Pink</label></li>

                <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="watermelon_red" value="Watermelon Red" name="board_colors[]">
                    <label for="watermelon_red">Watermelon Red</label></li>

                <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="true_red" value="True Red" name="board_colors[]">
                    <label for="true_red">True Red</label></li>

                <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="orange" value="Orange" name="board_colors[]">
                    <label for="orange">Orange</label></li>
            </ul>       
                <span><label for="board_colors[]" class="error"></label></span>
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: What's your representative HTML?

Comment: Just added the html for the checkbox section of the form...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd personally suggest adding a class to the parent `<li>` element and then styling the text of the `<label>` using CSS:

```
$('input:checkbox[name="board_colors[]"]').on('change', function () {
    // cache your inputs for repeated access:
    var inputs = $('input[type="checkbox"][name="board_colors[]"]'),
        // using the cached jQuery object, filtering for the :checked elements:
        nightLifeLimit = inputs.filter(':checked').length;
    // iterating over each of the elements:
    inputs.each(function () {
        // 'this' is the current input:
        $(this)
        // disabling if it's not checked *and* if the limit is reached:
        .prop('disabled', !this.checked && nightLifeLimit == 2)
        // moving to the closest 'li' ancestor:
        .closest('li')
        // adding the class if the checkbox is disabled, removing if not:
        .toggleClass('disabled', this.disabled);
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/a5KSM/).

That said, if you move the `<input />` elements before the `<label>` elements, giving:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Choose color(s) <small class="fineprint">*choose up to two</small></legend>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="bright_green" value="Bright Green" name="board_colors[]" title="Please choose a color(s)" required="" minlength="1" />
            <label for="bright_green">Bright Green</label>
        </li>
        <!-- others removed for brevity -->
    </ul> <span><label for="board_colors[]" class="error"></label></span>

</fieldset>
```

You could simply use CSS to style the sibling `<label>` elements:

```
input[type=checkbox]:disabled + label {
    color: #ccc;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/a5KSM/1/).

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Comment: You're very welcome indeed; the way you phrased your comment suggests that the first demo didn't work, or didn't work as you required?

Comment: Correct. And to make sure, I just tested it again. It does not grey out the remaining choices after the checkbox limit has been reached.

Comment: Can I ask what browser/OS you're using, because the first works (disables the checkboxes and greys out the text) for me (Chrome on both Android and Windows XP, and Safari on iPad Air).

Comment: Does the linked demo (the JS Fiddle) not work, or is it when you use the code in your own page? I'm bemused by the demo not working for you when it does for me :-/

Comment: Ah, okay; that's a bit less weird, then. Though no less irritating. Any obvious errors reported by the console?

Comment: It has something to do with another piece of JS I am using that hides the actual checkbox. If I take those out of the equation, your first demo works for me.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is you set a class to parent element that tells us that the amount of maximum allowable item is selected. 
Then apply with css gray text. [Example code](http://jsfiddle.net/MiguelR/VDnkP/2/)

CSS

```
.max-element input:not(:checked) + label {color: lightgray;}
```

SJ

```
$('input:checkbox[name="board_colors[]"]').change(function () {
var nightLifeLimit = $('input:checkbox[name="board_colors[]"]:checked').length;
    if (nightLifeLimit > 1) {
       $('input:checkbox[name="board_colors[]"]').each(function () {
          $(this).is(':checked') ? null : $(this).prop("disabled", true);
       });
       $(this).closest('ul').addClass('max-element');
    }
    else {
        $('input:checkbox[name="board_colors[]"]').prop('disabled', false);
        $(this).closest('ul').removeClass('max-element');
    }
});
```

Note: Attribute minlength not allowed on element input. You can use data-minlength="1".

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me. I edited my original post to include a link to a test page so all of the code, css, and js can be seen.